# Gradle with DataBinding failed when upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding

I get the following gradle error when building the project:

> Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0-beta1.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>     Required by:
>         project :ConsultUIKit > project :HealthBase
>   Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0-beta1.
>     Searched in the following locations:

Required by:
      project :ConsultUIKit > project :HealthBase > com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1
      project :ConsultUIKit > project :HealthBase > com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1

and here is my build.gradle:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `google()` repo to your project's `repositories` configuration, e.g.:

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven).